# Assign custom class instance to variable with get-Function

Tags: vba, class

I have two classes:

**clsDataElement**

```
Public dataA As String
Public dataB As String
Public dataC As String
```

**clsInterface**

```
Private mDataElements() As clsDataElement
Private mCountOfDataElements As Integer

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   mCountOfDataElements = 0
End Sub

Public Sub addDataElement(dataElement As clsDataElement)
   ReDim Preserve mDataElements(mCountOfDataElements)
   Set mDataElements(mCountOfDataElements) = New clsDataElement

   mDataElements(mCountOfDataElements).dataA = dataElement.dataA 
   mDataElements(mCountOfDataElements).dataB = dataElement.dataB 
   mDataElements(mCountOfDataElements).dataC = dataElement.dataC

   mCountOfDataElements = mCountOfDataElements + 1
End Sub

Public Function getDataElement(Optional index As Integer) As clsDataElement
   If Not index >= mCountOfDataElements Then
      getDataElement = mDataElements(index)
   End If
End Function
```

So as you can see, the class `clsDataElement` is just a containe for some data.
The class `clsInterface` can contain multiple Elements of `clsDataElement`

Now if I want to read one Data Element from the interface class, it just does not work. However, I feel like this is related to the fact, that I cannot just assign custom classes:

```
Public Sub TestMyClass(myInterface As clsInterface)
    Dim tmpDataElement As New clsDataElement
    Set tmpDataElement = myInterface.getDataElement(0)
End Sub
```

So when running this code I get the error

> Object variable or with block variable not set

I made sure that there are multiple data elements stored in myInterface. 
Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you missing the 'Set' keyword when getting the element:

```
Public Function getDataElement(Optional index As Integer) As clsDataElement
   If Not index >= mCountOfDataElements Then
      Set getDataElement = mDataElements(index)
   End If
End Function
```